# SIGSEGV segmentation fault

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, strftime

I am following a tutorial to setup client server communication using sockets in Linux. I am observing SIGSEGV segmentation fault in strftime() call. I tried debugging values and am not sure where the fault is. Can anyone help ?

```
    int socketOk;
    int fds[2];
    pid_t child_proc;

    socketOk = socketpair(AF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM, 0, fds);

    if((child_proc = fork()) == (pid_t) -1) {
        //Fork Failure case
        printf("\n ERR-%s: fork() failed \n", strerror(errno));
    }


    else if(child_proc == 0) {
        //Fork Child case

        printf("\n Child: Child process created under Server PID - %d \n", getppid());

        close(fds[0]);
        fds[0] = -1;

        printf("\n Child: Requesting Date in a specific format from Server");
        char *timeFormatPtrChild;
        //timeFormatPtrChild = "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S";
        timeFormatPtrChild = "%A %d-%b-%Y %l:%M %p";
        int writeOk = write(fds[1], timeFormatPtrChild, strlen(timeFormatPtrChild));
        printf("\n Child: Request sent to Server - %s \n", (writeOk==-1 ? "Unsuccessful" : "Successful"));

        char timeStringChild[50];
        int readOk = read(fds[1], timeStringChild, sizeof timeStringChild);
        timeStringChild[readOk] = 0;
        if(readOk >= 0) {
            printf("\n Child: Date received from server - %s \n", timeStringChild);
        }
        else {
            printf("\n ERR-%s: read() failed in client \n", strerror(errno));
        }

        fflush(stdout);

        close(fds[0]);

    }
    else {
        //Fork Parent case

        close(fds[1]);
        fds[1]=-1;

        printf("\n Server: Child process created with PID-%d \n", child_proc);

        printf("\n Server: Waiting for Child request");
        char timeString[80];
        char timeFormatPtr[50];
        int readOk = read(fds[0], timeFormatPtr, sizeof timeFormatPtr);
        printf("\n Server: Received Time format from Child - %s \n", (readOk==-1 ? "Unsuccessful" : timeFormatPtr));
        timeFormatPtr[readOk] = 0;

        time_t timePtr;
        time(&timePtr);
        strftime(timeString, sizeof timeString, timeFormatPtr, localtime(&timePtr));


        int writeOk = write(fds[0], timeString, strlen(timeString));
        if(writeOk >= 0) {
            printf("\n Server: Date sent to Child - %s \n", timeString);
        }
        else {
            printf("\n ERR-%s: write() failed in Server \n", strerror(errno));
        }

        int status;
        close(fds[0]);

        waitpid(child_proc, &status, 0);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: one problem is that you read up to `sizeof timeFormatPtr` and then add a NUL which might be out of bounds. But that applies only if you really read 50 bytes. Another thing is that you call `printf( "...%s...",  ... timeFormatPtr ):` before NUL terminating

Comment: What if `read` returns `-1`? You just continue processing.

Comment: Do you have an example of this failing because when I compile the code it works "ok" - i.e. without `SIGSEGV`

Comment: as @rustyx says, `read` failing returns `-1` and then you'll be accessing `timeStringChild[-1]` so you need to fix that and check for the return value before using the value.

Comment: Hi All. I checked why read() wasnt returning. Problem seems to lie in strftime() call which throws SIGSEGV error. Fixed it with including the time.h header in the file. Strange, why it throws SIGSEGV instead of something like 'undefined reference'...